# How to get the playlist_id from a playlist using spotipy?

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

so i'm trying to figure out on how to get the playlist_id from the play list I created, but I have no luck finding which method to use even after reading the spotipy docutmentation.

```
import spotipy
import json
import sys
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import requests
import os
import dotenv
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID="secret"
SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET="secret"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope="playlist-modify-private",
                                                            client_id=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
                                                            client_secret=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                                            redirect_uri="https://google.com",
                                                            cache_path="token.txt"))
user_id = sp.current_user()["id"] # grabs user name
sp.user_playlist_create(user_id,"Funky Music",public=False,collaborative=False, description="Test")
```

This is how far I've gotten into the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
playlist= sp.user_playlist_create(user_id,"Funky Music",public=False,collaborative=False, description="Test")

playlist_id = playlist["id"]
```